# Bayesian CNN for regression Task

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, bayesian-networks, tensorflow-probability

I have a standard CNN model to solve a regression task in a picture dataset. The model is implemented using Tensorflow and works great on my dataset:

```py
def create_cnn_model() -> Model:
    cnn = models.Sequential()
    cnn.add(layers.Conv2D(32, 3, 3, activation="relu", input_shape=(450, 800, 3)))
    cnn.add(layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
    cnn.add(layers.Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation="relu"))
    cnn.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
    cnn.add(layers.Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation="relu"))

    cnn.add(layers.Flatten())

    cnn.add(layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
    cnn.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
    cnn.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))

    cnn.compile(
        optimizer="adam",
        loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    )

    return cnn
```

Now I would like to change the CNN to a Bayesian CNN model so I can calculate the confidence of the prediction and also an interval (min-max prediction). For this I tried to use the library `tensorflow-probability` like the following:

```py
def create_bcnn_model(train_size) -> Model:
    bcnn = models.Sequential()
    bcnn.add(layers.Conv2D(32, 3, 3, activation="relu", input_shape=(450, 800, 3)))
    bcnn.add(layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
    bcnn.add(layers.Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation="relu"))
    bcnn.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
    bcnn.add(layers.Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation="relu"))

    bcnn.add(layers.Flatten())

    hidden_units = [128, 64]
    for units in hidden_units:
        bcnn.add(tfp.layers.DenseVariational(
            units=units,
            make_prior_fn=prior,
            make_posterior_fn=posterior,
            kl_weight=1 / train_size,
            activation="relu",
        ))

    bcnn.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))

    bcnn.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0005),
        loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()],
    )

    return bcnn
```

where I essentially switch out the standard Dense Layers with DenseVariational layers. I mostly just followed the tutorial from [keras.io](https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/bayesian_neural_networks/).
But I can't get it to work and get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Input right-most shape (566353984) does not correspond to a triangular matrix.
```

Is it not allowed to mix standard tensorflow layers with tfp layers? Are there any good examples for a Bayesian CNN for a regression task? All the examples I could find is about classification.
I would greatly appreciate any hints or tips in any direction :)

EDIT:
My prior and posterior are the same as from the keras example:

```py
def prior(kernel_size, bias_size, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    prior_model = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
                lambda t: tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(
                    loc=tf.zeros(n), scale_diag=tf.ones(n)
                )
            )
        ]
    )
    return prior_model


def posterior(kernel_size, bias_size, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    posterior_model = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            tfp.layers.VariableLayer(
                tfp.layers.MultivariateNormalTriL.params_size(n), dtype=dtype
            ),
            tfp.layers.MultivariateNormalTriL(n),
        ]
    )
    return posterior_model
```

Comment: That error is related to your prior or posterior, can't tell without seeing them. Also your output is still deterministic. You might be interested in [Convolution2DReparameterization](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/layers/Convolution2DReparameterization) and [DenseReparameterization](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/layers/DenseReparameterization). DenseVariational will give you the advantage of specifying KL weight, working with Reparameterization layers should be easier to work with for your case.

Comment: My prior and posterior are the same from the keras example, nevertheless I added them to the post @Frightera

Comment: Try to replace Flatten with GlobalMaxPooling2D. Also you will notice that model will have too many parameters. I am not sure if you still want to train it after normal CNN.

Comment: GlobalMaxPooling2D is working and it is training my model! However, now most of the predictions on the validation data set are negative while non of the labels it is training on has a negative value. Do you have any ideas why that is happening? Anyways, thanks for your help

Comment: Your output is linear so the network can output any range of values including negatives. I'd try to simplify the network a bit.